# Return different random PHP variable per use

Tags: php

I have this PHP variable set up in a variables file:

```
$random_annotation = $config->urls->templates . '/img/annotations/Annotations-' . str_pad(rand(1, 40), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '.svg';
```

If I use `<?php echo $random_annotation; ?>` multiple times on the page it returns the same 'random' value. Is there a way for it to return a different value each time it is used?

Comment: Put that in a function, and invoke it when you need it.

Comment: If you only set the variable once, then it's only ever going to have that one value.  If you want to generate a random value multiple times, generate one multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your variable inside a function block like follows:

```
function random_ann() {
    $random_annotation = $config->urls->templates . '/img/annotations/Annotations-' . str_pad(rand(1, 40), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '.svg';
    return $random_annotation;
}
random_ann(); // A random expected string
```

That is because you are saving your `$random_annotation` variable at once and not changing it before retrieving it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to seed the random number generator. (Try using the System time)

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php) is the documentation for PHP.